# Stop Google Compute instance from configuring second network interface

Tags: dhcp, google-compute-engine, systemd-networkd

I'm spinning up a VM in Google Compute Engine running Debian Buster, and configuring it with two network interfaces.

The first uses an ephemeral IP config, and is assigned to a publicly routable network, configured via DHCP. I'd like to keep this as is.

The second interface uses a static IP config, and is assigned to a private network. I'd like to stop GCE from using DHCP to configure this interface, and instead use systemd-networkd to configure it myself, for the purpose of easily adding some custom routes.

While the systemd-networkd configuration does work successfully, the problem is that when the machine is rebooted, GCE's DHCP setup is running after the systemd-networkd setup, and overwriting my custom config.

I've tried numerous things to resolve this issue so far, including:

- Disable the entry for /var/run/interfaces.d in /etc/network/interfaces
- Add a custom systemd service to run after GCE's networking services

The only thing that's worked thus far is a hideous script hack to wait 30 seconds after boot, then kick off systemd-networkd again to overwrite the GCE config.

Is there some cleaner configuration change I can make at the OS level, or a configuration setting during network/server setup that will prevent GCE from auto configuring this second network interface?

EDIT #1:

This is an example of the systemd-networkd configuration I'd prefer to use:

```
[Match]
Name=ens5

[Network]
Address=10.1.3.30/32
LinkLocalAddressing=no


[Route]
Destination=10.1.3.1/32
Scope=link

[Route]
Gateway=10.1.3.1
Destination=10.1.3.0/24
GatewayOnlink=yes

[Route]
Gateway=10.1.3.1
Destination=10.1.1.0/24
GatewayOnlink=yes

[Route]
Gateway=10.1.3.1
Destination=10.1.2.0/24
GatewayOnlink=yes

[Route]
Gateway=10.1.3.1
Destination=10.10.0.0/24
GatewayOnlink=yes
```

Using this configuration allows me to set additional routes on the interface to other subnets. Note that these other subnets may or may not be on GCP.

The above configuration works, even given that I have to declare the 10.1.3.30 static IP address as part of my GCE server setup. The problem is only that I can't get GCE to stop doing its own configuration of the interface, which overwrites the one above. On Azure, I can simply comment out the `source` reference to `/var/run/network/interfaces.d` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

As for why I'd prefer this setup, it's an elegant method for setting up my internal network via my server configuration management software -- I just drop the above config into `/etc/systemd/network/` and issue `systemctl enable systemd-networkd && systemctl restart systemd-networkd`, and it handles configuring the interface and setting the configuration to also happen on boot.

UPDATE #1:

I've filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153513472 in GCP's issue tracker, hopefully they'll address. I'll update the issue accordingly when they do.

UPDATE #2:

After a round with paid GCP support, they've pointed me to another ongoing issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167371074

The support agent also suggested other users have simply put cron scripts in place to restart the network periodically.

I've adapted this suggestion for my specific network needs, with the following crontab entry:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/test -z "$(/sbin/ip route | /bin/grep "10.1.1.0/24")" && /bin/systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Where '10.1.1.0/24' is a subnet that I know in my routing config should *not* be missing.

UPDATE #3:

Finally, a clean and satisfying answer! Google engineers informed me that the `google-guest-agent.service` which runs as part of their guest environment on Debian systems has a network daemon, which, when it re-configures any interfaces, calls `dhclient` directly. It would seem that `dhclient` called this way wipes out existing routes. Given that, an easy workaround is to create a dhclient exit-hook by adding a shell script in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/`.

In my case, I added the following script at `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/systemd-networkd`:

```
case $reason in
    BOUND|RENEW|REBIND|REBOOT)
        systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
        ;;
esac
```

This seems to solve the problem, including across reboots.

Comment: It looks like this way is unsupported by GCP. Have a look at the documentation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#networkaddresses and https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#using_a_static_internal_ip_address_for_a_secondary_network_interface. Please provide more information about your use case.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I've added an example systemd-networkd config to my original question, and provided some rationale for my use case.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work in that way. You can file feature request under [this component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187257&template=1162722).

Comment: Please update your question with link to feature request at Issue Tracker if you decided to proceed in that way.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza thx for the issue tracker link. I've updated OP to include the issue link as you requested.

Comment: Thank you! Please mark my answer as accepted if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't realize such scenario on GCP at the moment. You can use described ways to manage internal IPs by following documentation like [Using a static internal IP address for a secondary network interface](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#using_a_static_internal_ip_address_for_a_secondary_network_interface).

As a possible workaround you can file [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) on [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under [this component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187257&template=1162722).